# Wordpress site is overlapped with another site

Tags: wordpress, plesk

Good day!

I have a problem with my site. I have used wordpress as my cms on plesk. Now, I have accidentally pressed 'publish site' on the prensence builder in plesk after which, my wordpress site is overlapped with the site that has been made using presence builder in plesk. I have no idea on how to get my wordpress site back. How can i disable the ones on the presence builder? Can I get my wordpress site back without installing it back? I really want my wordpress site back. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you did? Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: @Gunaseelan Everytime i head over to my site, the one that has been made using the presence builder will show up, not the ones i've made in wordpress.

Comment: Please provide the site url

Comment: @Gunaseelan https://stage3clan.com/ . If you head over to this site, that is the one that replaced with the site i've made in wordpress. I visited back the presence builder and accidentally click publish site, now instead of my wordpress site, that one would show up. how can i revert it back and use my wordpress site?

Comment: url is giving privacy error.

Answer (score 0):

SiteBuilder's publish button copy SB's site files into web root folder of your domain, for example `/httpdocs/`

And sitebuilder's `index.html` just overlaps WordPess's `index.php.`

So you can just rename `/httpdocs/index.html` in to something like `/httpdocs/index-sitebuilder.html` and you should see now your WordPress site.